# I want to automate the tunneling of putty such that Source port and destination can be entered automatically and then putty opens automatically

Tags: linux, ssh, java, python, tunnel

I want to automate the tunneling of putty such that Source port and destination can be entered automatically and then putty opens automatically.
*strong text*

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY allows you set all the necessary condition (tunneling, x11, etc) and then you can save them as a profile (Saved Session).

So the next time you want to run it, just load the profile, and it will have all the setting you saved previously